# Latin characters in Japanese?

Tags: pronunciation

So, I have the following sentence:

> 私は World of Tanks をします。

I am certain this sentence is laid out correctly. However, I am unsure of how I would pronounce "World of Tanks". Should I simply pronounce it (and any other titles that appear in Latin characters) as I would in English or as if it were written in katakana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you would pronounce it as though it were in katakana: ワールド・オブ・タンクス. Not doing so may lead to confusion. Although I must ask, why is it so important it be written in Roman letters?

Comment: As far as I know of, "World of Tanks" is simply displayed as "World of Tanks" on the Japanese translation of the website, so I am simply using that.

Comment: I must ask: Do you think ordinary Japanese people are able to pronounce it as you would in English? :-) Even bilingual speakers usually automatically katakanizes these words in their mind when they're talking to Japanese people.